# Multiple choice programming test / quiz for interview

Tags: web-apps, survey

Years ago (circa 2005?) I was asked by the company I was then working for to trial an online multiple choice test that would be used for screening candidates programming skills - specifically Java and C++.

The questions were multiple choice - but rather than simply having a fixed script of questions, the system would adapt the difficulty so it would pick harder questions if you were doing well and easier questions if you weren't.

I can't remember the name of the company ("mind tree" perhaps? or "brain cert") I'm trying to find out if this company is still going, or if there are any other companies offering a similar thing.

Comment: A similar approach is used by Pluralsight's "learning path" feature. When you assess yourself for the optimum level, that's the algorithm they apply. No source code, unfortunately, all closed.

Comment: Is it like Hacker Rank?